# scrapy stuck in DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash

I scrapy the html sucessful but splash.

Don't know why it fail to Crawl.

The code using splash below,

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class Spidernav(scrapy.Spider):
name = "navarea"

def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
        'http://www1.kaiho.mlit.go.jp/TUHO/keiho/navarea11_en.html?fbclid=IwAR0NCPNZb0esQcqHL9nWPt9NaB9FaKhRU769_sdiUfsOJY8Rf-rOUmkFAWA'
    ]
    splash_args = {'wait': 0.5}
    for url in urls:
        yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, args=splash_args, endpoint='render.html')

def parse(self, response):
    logging.info('done')

    # filename = 'navarea.html'
    # with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    #     f.write(response)
    # self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

but it always stucked here did'nt go on:

```
2018-12-15 12:57:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-12-15 12:57:18 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-12-15 12:57:18 [navarea] INFO: Spider opened: navarea
2018-12-15 12:57:18 [navarea] INFO: Spider opened: navarea
2018-12-15 12:57:18 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6032
```

and a few minutes later, it show this behind:

```
2018-12-15 12:58:18 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-12-15 12:58:33 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www1.kaiho.mlit.go.jp/TUHO/keiho/navarea11_en.html?fbclid=IwAR0NCPNZb0esQcqHL9nWPt9NaB9FaKhRU769_sdiUfsOJY8Rf-rOUmkFAWA via http://192.168.203.92:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): TCP connection timed out: 60: Operation timed out.
```

Comment: Problem solved:

   `SPLASH_URL = ' http:// 127.0.0.1:8050'` ,instead `'SPLASH_URL = 127.0.0.1:8050'`

Comment: I have the same problem, may you explain your solution?